# What's the difference between /ɒ/ and /ɑ/?

Tags: pronunciation

> He nearly swallowed it.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

[Jim Dale’s audio](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/348)
[Stephen Fry’s audio](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/349)

How does Jim Dale pronounce the a in swallowed: /ɒ/ or /ɑ/?
Considering his nationality, it seems more likely /ɒ/. But it doesn’t sound like how Stephen Fry pronounces. I want to know which one Jim Dale pronounces and what the difference between the two is.

Comment: I don'tthink either of them is /ɑ/. Stephen Fry and Jim Dale are both British. (And just to confuse things further, I am American but pronounce swallow with /ɔ/ and not /ɑ/: i.e., the vowel I use in caller, and not the one I use in collar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't actually hear any difference. To the extent that there *is* one, it's regional variation in pronunciation of the same phoneme [(**ɒ** as in *hot, odd, wash*)](http://www.worldwidewords.org/pronguide.htm). But OP might wish to note comment #3 here...

[In AmE, **ɑ:** and **ɒ** are one vowel, so **calm** and **cot** have the same vowel. In American transcriptions, **hot** is written as **hɑ:t**](http://www.worldwidewords.org/pronguide.htm)

Comment: Well ... the majority of the /ɒ/'s turn into /ɑ/ in the U.S., but in the Eastern half of the U.S. there are a large number that turn into /ɔ/.

Comment: @Peter: I think [the first three posters here](http://msgboard.snopes.com/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=95;t=000460;p=0) are all American. The first one says *Caller, Collar, Color* are exact homophones to him. The second one says **Caller, Collar* are the same, but *color* is different. The third one says all three are different. Even though for a Brit I have a relatively restricted phoneme set, they're all different to me.

Comment: Merging *collar* and *caller* is pretty standard in American accents (most people in the Western half of the country merge *cot* and *caught*, and quite a few in the East). But *color* and *caller* surprises me.

Comment: FF, that's an interesting answer. There seems to be a USA/UK difference in pronouncing that sound.

Comment: @Peter Shor: To be honest, I'd have been quite prepared to believe *all* Americans consistently pronounce *Caller, Collar, Color* as ***Carler***, and *cot, caught* as ***cart***. Just as we can usually discern all the relevant words on very low bit-rate voice communication channels, people seem to be quite good at overcoming (or not even noticing! :) variations in pronunciation that have no real semantic significance (unless for some reason you're particularly interested in knowing more about the speaker's geographical or social background, etc.).

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm an American and I pronounce "caller", "collar", and "color" differently. I'm sometimes surprised at the amount of regional variation. My daughter was playing with some app on her phone that asked how you pronounced various words and then showed which parts of the US used each pronunciation. Much more variation that I would have expected. Apparently even though I haven't lived in New York for 35 years, I still have a New York accent. And as my kids have a father from New York but grew up in Ohio, they have a mix of New York and Ohio accents.

Comment: @Jay: People vary enormously in how strongly they retain an accent. My father has lived in southern Britain for over 75 years, but he still has a very strong Lancashire accent. I myself, on the other hand, am known to friends and family for starting to adopt the local accent if I even spend a week or two on holiday somewhere. And I'm not aware that I make any particular effort to do this (or to avoid it happening).